# Android sqlite: How to search by second word in value?

Tags: java, android

I have snippets of code where I search contacts by string `"niv"`:

```
idCursor = mApp.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID },
        "( display_name LIKE ? ) OR ( data1 LIKE ? )",
        new String[] {"niv%", "niv%"},
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
```

So this query looks for contacts where email (`data1`) or `display_name` starts with `niv`. It should catch case where `display_name` is `Niv The Great`

But whats happens if `display_name` is `Great Niv`. Second word starts from `niv`

How can I write query wisely to do not affect on search performance but to take 2nd case?

**Expected behaviour**

- `Niv The Great`: matches
- `Great Niv`:  matches
- `Kaniv The Great`: not matches
- `Great Roniv`: not matches

Answer (score 0):

add the wildcard `%` before and after the parameter value with something like this: `( display_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%')`
that way it´ll search wherever the char sequence occurs

Comment: but I need `statWith`, not `contains`

Comment: Then use `?% ?℅`, you see? Leave the whitespace as a must

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in W3C [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) for `SQL LIKE` operator you can use:

- `"s%"` filtering words started with 's';
- `"%s"` filtering words finished with 's';
- `"%s%"` filtering words containing 's'.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below way:

```
String query="SELECT *
  FROM Crop_Mst
 WHERE varDesc LIKE '%a%' 
       OR
       varName LIKE '%a%'";

rawQuery(query, null);
```

Use filter as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
idCursor = mApp.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID },
    "( display_name LIKE ? ) OR ( data1 LIKE ? )",
    new String[] {"niv%", "niv%","%niv%"},
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
```

add one more in your where query i.e. %s%

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
idCursor = mApp.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID },
    "( display_name LIKE ? ) OR ( display_name LIKE ? ) OR ( data1 LIKE ? ) OR ( data1 LIKE ? )",
    new String[] {"niv%" , "% niv%", "niv%", "% niv%"},
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
```

Comment: Well, it should work only if String contains 2 words only. What about cases like: `Abu al kasam` or `Nei van Holder`?

Comment: what is your requirement?It should work if it contains any number of words?

Comment: I expect to search by `startWith` for every word in `display_name` column